# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AccountsController::index(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, eloquent

The session is being destroyed after successfully logged in or there's some error with the guard that couldn't retain the session. When asked for `your_session_key` the on the view of the dashboard, it provides null.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::namespace('Admin')->group(function () {
        Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin_middle','auth:admin']] , function () {
            Route::get('accounts/', 'AccountsController@index')->name('admin.accounts');
        });
    });
});
```

Middleware:

```
class RedirectIfNotAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
    {
        if (!auth()->guard($guard)->check()) {
            $request->session()->flash('error', 'You must be an Admin to see this page');
            return redirect(route('auth.admin.login'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Guard: config/auth.php // Custom Guard

```
'guards' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
],
```

AccountsController:

```
class AccountsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(AdminRepositoryInterface $adminRepository) {
        $this->adminRepo = $adminRepository;
    }

    private $adminRepo;
    public function index(int $id)
    {
        $admin = $this->adminRepo->findAdminById($id);
        $talentRepo = new AdminRepository($admin);
        return view('admin.accounts');
    }
}
```

AdminRepositoryInterface: App\Shop\Admins\Repositories\Interfaces\AdminRepositoryInterface;

```
interface AdminRepositoryInterface extends BaseRepositoryInterface
{
    public function findAdminById(int $id) : Admin;
}
```

AdminRepository: App\Shop\Admins\Repositories\AdminRepository

```
class AdminRepository extends BaseRepository implements AdminRepositoryInterface
{
    public function findAdminById(int $id) : Admin
    {
        try {
            return $this->findOneOrFail($id);
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new AdminNotFoundException($e);
        }
    }
}
```

View: admin\accounts.blade

```
@if (Session::has('YOUR_SESSION_KEY'))
{{-- do something with session key --}} 
@else
{{-- session key does not exist  --}} //this has been printed is the ID variable is not passed
@endif
{{$admin->name}}
<br />{{$admin->email}}
```

Comment: You defined index as `public function index(int $id)`, expecting an `$id`. Your route is `Route::get('accounts/', 'AccountsController@index')`, with no id. They need to match.

Comment: Hi @aynber , The Id should be from Session.

Comment: Then you need to take it out of the index definition and get it from the session inside of the function, instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate and show some code?

Comment: The error you get is pretty self explainatory.

Comment: @Refilon I am not able to use the session key, please see in the accounts.blade, the last file.

Comment: The error is not explanatory, The session has not been initiated

Answer (score 1):

Your controller expects an ID, but your route doen't have any parameter.

As you pointed out in the comments, you want to get the ID from the session.

You can get something out of the session using `$value = session('key');`

So your controller should look like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $id = session('nameOfSessionKey');
    $admin = $this->adminRepo->findAdminById($id);
    $talentRepo = new AdminRepository($admin);

    return view('admin.accounts');
}
```

Read more about sessions in the Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/session)

Comment: That's the main issue, I am not able to use the session key. I have mentioned in the accounts.blade in the last file.

Comment: Your key is named "YOUR_SESSION_KEY"?

Comment: Yes, please see in accounts.blade:
if (Session::has('YOUR_SESSION_KEY'))
{{-- do something with session key --}} 
else
{{-- session key does not exist  --}} //this has been printed is the ID variable is not passed
endif